# PayPal PHP SDK throws an error 'Class Not Found'?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to use `PayPal PHP SDK` in my project an dso far I haven't had much luck with it.

I've installed the SDK on my server using `composer`. Tested it to make sure it all works and I see the Logs successfully being logged in my PayPal developer account. So I know the installation was successfull.

Now, I'm trying to use the PayPal PHP SDK to create a single Payout as shown on here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/reference/setup-sdk/#set-up-the-environment

But I get this error everytime I run my code:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PaypalPayoutsSDK\\Core\\SandboxEnvironment' not found
```

During my research about this issue, I came across a few similar questions on Stackoverflow and they pointed the fact the word `Paypal` should be changed to `PayPal` with `Capital P`.

So I went ahead and did that but I still get this error:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PayPalPayoutsSdk\\Core\\SandboxEnvironment' not found
```

So, I am stuck now and I really don't understand why PayPal will release an incomplete and buggy SDK which seems to be full of typos!

This is my entire code:

```
<?php
namespace Sample;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


use PayPalPayoutsSDK\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalPayoutsSDK\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
// Creating an environment
$clientId = "Af-I0mFTWp0mpf2423NWWnGrfAFajiszEJtg8N10.....";
$clientSecret = "687684OjSRWTYJ.....";

$environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);



use PayPalPayoutsSDK\Payouts\PayoutsPostRequest;
$request = new PayoutsPostRequest();
$body= json_decode(
            '{
                "sender_batch_header":
                {
                  "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn"
                },
                "items": [
                {
                  "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                  "receiver": "sb-uo5q4745644@business.example.com",
                  "note": "Your 1£ payout",
                  "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                  "amount":
                  {
                    "currency": "GBP",
                    "value": "1.00"
                  }
                }]
              }',             
            true);
$request->body = $body;
$client = PayPalClient::client();
$response = $client->execute($request);
print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
print "Status: {$response->result->batch_header->batch_status}\n";
print "Batch ID: {$response->result->batch_header->payout_batch_id}\n";
print "Links:\n";
foreach($response->result->links as $link)
 {
   print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
 }
echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";

?>
```

Could someone please advice on this issue as i spent 2 days on this to no avail.

Comment: is it something to do with double \\ ? isn't it supposed to be single \?

Comment: Did you try composer dump-autoload ( or composer dump-autoload  -o ). https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-1-class-map-generation

Comment: You can take a look inside your vendor folder to check the classnames and namespaces of your package. There you will see if a capital P is required, I think no.

Comment: @Benni, which file in the vendor folder?

Comment: @Rali what would that do?

Comment: @James Juanjie, first, do dump-autoload as Rali suggested, then change back to lowercase p and try again

Comment: @Benni did that and now I'm getting this error:`Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"` But I have checked my clientID and Secret Key against the ones in my paypal developer account and they are correct!!

Comment: @JamesJuanjie It regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project